# Пересыл сообщений с помощью ID

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Как сделать, чтобы бот пересылал сообщения из переписки с ботом другим людям по их ID? Хотелось бы узнать структуру кода, хотя бы один пример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**await bot.forward_message(...)**

*Параметры:*

**chat_id**: Union[int, str]
Unique identifier for the target chat or username of the target channel (in the format @channelusername)

**from_chat_id**: Union[int, str]
Unique identifier for the chat where the original message was sent (or channel username in the format @channelusername)

**message_id**: int
Message identifier in the chat specified in from_chat_id

**disable_notification**:
Optional[bool]
Sends the message silently. Users will receive a notification with no sound.

1. Получаете id человека, которому необходимо отправить сообщение (**Важно!** Бот не может инициировать диалог)
2. Берете id чата (откуда переслать) и id сообщения
3. Profit :)

Пример:

```
...
await bot.forward_message(chat_id=123123123, from_chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id)
...
```